# How to speed up spaCy lemmatization?

Tags: performance, nlp, spacy

I'm using spaCy (version 2.0.11) for lemmatization in the first step of my NLP pipeline but unfortunately it's taking a verrry long time. It is clearly the slowest part of my processing pipeline and I want to know if there are improvements I could be making. I am using a pipeline as:

```
nlp.pipe(docs_generator, batch_size=200, n_threads=6, disable=['ner'])
```

on a 8 core machine, and I have verified that the machine is using all the cores.

On a corpus of about 3 million short texts totaling almost 2gb it takes close to 24hrs to lemmatize and write to disk. Reasonable?

I have tried disabling a couple parts of the processing pipeline and found that it broke the lemmatization (parser, tagger).

**Are there any parts of the default processing pipeline that are not required for lemmatization besides named entity recognition?**

**Are there other ways of speeding up the spaCy lemmatization process?**

Aside:

It also appears that documentation doesn't list all the operations in the parsing pipeline. At the top of the spacy Language class we have:

```
factories = {
    'tokenizer': lambda nlp: nlp.Defaults.create_tokenizer(nlp),
    'tensorizer': lambda nlp, **cfg: Tensorizer(nlp.vocab, **cfg),
    'tagger': lambda nlp, **cfg: Tagger(nlp.vocab, **cfg),
    'parser': lambda nlp, **cfg: DependencyParser(nlp.vocab, **cfg),
    'ner': lambda nlp, **cfg: EntityRecognizer(nlp.vocab, **cfg),
    'similarity': lambda nlp, **cfg: SimilarityHook(nlp.vocab, **cfg),
    'textcat': lambda nlp, **cfg: TextCategorizer(nlp.vocab, **cfg),
    'sbd': lambda nlp, **cfg: SentenceSegmenter(nlp.vocab, **cfg),
    'sentencizer': lambda nlp, **cfg: SentenceSegmenter(nlp.vocab, **cfg),
    'merge_noun_chunks': lambda nlp, **cfg: merge_noun_chunks,
    'merge_entities': lambda nlp, **cfg: merge_entities
}
```

which includes some items not covered in the documentation here: 
https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines

Since they are not covered I don't really know which may be disabled, nor what their dependencies are.

Answer (score 11):

I found out you can disable the parser portion of the spacy pipeline as well, as long as you add the sentence segmenter. It's not crazy fast but it is definitely an improvement--in tests the time looks to be about 1/3 of what I was doing before (when I was just disabling 'ner'). Here is what I have now:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['ner', 'parser'])
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer'))
```

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue with a 1.5 million corpus. I disabled tagger, parser, and ner but still it has been running for 8 hours. Did you try with something else?

Answer (score 0):

- One quick and impactful optimization would be memoization using suitable inmemory structures or inmemory databases ( python dicts or redis/memcache ).
- Lemmatized forms of the words alongside with their context like Part-Of-Speech would be constant, and do not change, so there is no need to spend computing power on them again and again.
- There would be LOADS of repetitions in your 3 million text corpus, and memoization would cut down the time hugely.

Example:

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
>>> txt1 = u"he saw the dragon, he saw the forest, and used a saw to cut the tree, and then threw the saw in the river." 
>>> [(x.text,x.pos_,x.lemma_) for x in nlp(txt1)]
[(u'he', u'PRON', u'-PRON-'), (u'saw', u'VERB', u'see'), (u'the', u'DET', u'the'), (u'dragon', u'NOUN', u'dragon'), (u',', u'PUNCT', u','), (u'he', u'PRON', u'-PRON-'), (u'saw', u'VERB', u'see'), (u'the', u'DET', u'the'), (u'forest', u'NOUN', u'forest'), (u',', u'PUNCT', u','), (u'and', u'CCONJ', u'and'), (u'used', u'VERB', u'use'), (u'a', u'DET', u'a'), (u'saw', u'NOUN', u'saw'), (u'to', u'PART', u'to'), (u'cut', u'VERB', u'cut'), (u'the', u'DET', u'the'), (u'tree', u'NOUN', u'tree'), (u',', u'PUNCT', u','), (u'and', u'CCONJ', u'and'), (u'then', u'ADV', u'then'), (u'threw', u'VERB', u'throw'), (u'the', u'DET', u'the'), (u'saw', u'NOUN', u'saw'), (u'in', u'ADP', u'in'), (u'the', u'DET', u'the'), (u'river', u'NOUN', u'river'), (u'.', u'PUNCT', u'.')]
```

As you can see pos tag + lemmatized form are constant.

Comment: Are you sure you can consider them to be constant? If so why would it require the part of speech tagger? Here is what Wikipedia says about lemmatization: "Unlike stemming, lemmatisation depends on correctly identifying the intended part of speech and meaning of a word in a sentence, as well as within the larger context surrounding that sentence..."

Comment: I have modified the examples, it would be dependent on the words usage as a verb or noun etc.

Comment: Try this test on your text corpus : https://gist.github.com/dhruvpathak/a7b96f469fd404a2351de69a5ff41144

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a shot next week. My only worry would be memory, but I have plenty of that.

Comment: You can also use an external cache or fast database like redis, aerospike or mongodb for memoization.