# How to use spacys built in lemmatiser in a spacy pipeline?

Tags: nlp, pipeline, spacy

I want to use lemmatisation, but I can't directly see in the docs how to use Spacys built in lemmatisation in a pipeline.

In the docs [for the lemmatiser](https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer), it says:

> Initialize a Lemmatizer. Typically, this happens under the hood within spaCy when a `Language`
>   subclass and its `Vocab` is initialized.

Does this mean the build in lemmatisation process is an unmentioned part of the pipeline?

[It's mentioned in the docs as part of the pipeline subheading](https://spacy.io/api)

[image]

while in the [docs for the pipeline usage](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines) there is only mention of "custom lemmatisation" and how to use it.

[image]

This is all kind of conflicting information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean the build in lemmatisation process is an unmentioned part of the pipeline?

Simply, yes. The [Lemmatizer](https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer) is loaded when the `Language` and `Vocab` are loaded.

**Usage example**:

```py
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc= nlp(u"Apples and oranges are similar. Boots and hippos aren't.")
print('\n')
print("Token Attributes: \n", "token.text, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_, token.lemma_")
for token in doc:
    # Print the text and the predicted part-of-speech tag
    print("{:<12}{:<12}{:<12}{:<12}{:<12}".format(token.text, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_, token.lemma_))
```

**Output**:

```
Token Attributes: 
 token.text, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_, token.lemma_
Apples      NOUN        NNS         nsubj       apple       
and         CCONJ       CC          cc          and         
oranges     NOUN        NNS         conj        orange      
are         AUX         VBP         ROOT        be          
similar     ADJ         JJ          acomp       similar     
.           PUNCT       .           punct       .           
Boots       NOUN        NNS         nsubj       boot        
and         CCONJ       CC          cc          and         
hippos      NOUN        NN          conj        hippos      
are         AUX         VBP         ROOT        be          
n't         PART        RB          neg         not         
.           PUNCT       .           punct       .
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51372724/how-to-speed-up-spacy-lemmatization) thread as well, there is some interesting information regarding the speed of the lemmatization.